# My Samsung galaxy tab 2 does not switch on

Tags: operating-system

I am using Samsung galaxy tab 2 gt p3100. It freezes when showing Samsung galaxy tab 2 gtp3100. I cannot switch on my tablet neither switch off.

Comment: What has happened before? Did you try to install a new rom/recovery/rooted your tablet before this has happened? Can you access the "download mode"  ( long press POWER+Volume UP ) ? If so, you can download a Stock Firmware from sammobile.com and flash this firmware via Odin from your PC.

Comment: Apart from the details asked by Benjamin (which might give us other options), can you boot into [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info) or [recovery-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info)? If so, flashing the firmware again could possibly be avoided.

Comment: @benjaminS should be easy, since the GTP3110 and the GTP3100 are identical. I think the only difference is a never used sensor.